# Toggle javascript execution on/off with text link in html5 audio

Tags: javascript, html, function, toggle

I am using a code to highlight words that are read depending "on" the time, and it's on by default.  I need it to stay on by default, but add a function on a "text link" that can toggle the highlighting on/off (so there is no highlighting when clicked. So when I click the word "Disable", it disables the execution of the code, and the word "Disable" changes automatically to the word "Enable", which does the contrary.. etc.

And here is a snippet of the code:

```js
var spns = document.getElementsByTagName("SPAN");
var audi = document.getElementById("adi");

audi.addEventListener("timeupdate", f1);

function f1(){
  var i;  
  for (i = 0 ; i< spns.length ; i++){
    var time = Number(spns[i].id.slice(2));
    if(time < audi.currentTime){
      if (i>0) spns[i -1].style.backgroundColor = "white";  
      spns[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";  
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<audio id = "adi" controls>
  <source src="https://ia802508.us.archive.org/5/items/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3"></source>
</audio>

<div>
  <pre>
    <span id="ts0.5">Ok, we're trying this for a second time</span> , <span id="ts3">to test the ability...</span>
    </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use CSS and target the spans depending on parent's class. This makes the logic better less complicated.

```js
var textHighlightOn = true,
    btnToggle = document.getElementById('toggleTxt'),
    textDiv   =  document.querySelector('.text-highlight')
    spns = document.getElementsByTagName("SPAN"),
    audi = document.getElementById("adi");

audi.addEventListener("timeupdate", f1);

function f1(){
  var i;  
  for (i = 0 ; i< spns.length ; i++){
    var time = Number(spns[i].id.slice(2));
    if(time < audi.currentTime){
      
       if (i>0) {
       
           spns[i -1].classList.remove('active');
           spns[i -1].classList.add('active-prev');
       
       }
       
       spns[i].classList.add('active');
      
    }
  }
}

btnToggle.addEventListener("click", function(){

    if(textHighlightOn){
       textDiv.classList.add('off');
    } else {
       textDiv.classList.remove('off');
    }

    this.innerHTML = 'Highlight ' + (textHighlightOn ? 'off ' : ' on');         

    textHighlightOn = !textHighlightOn;

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #008000;
}
.text-highlight span.active-prev {
   background: #fff;
}
.text-highlight span.active {
   background: #03a9f4;
}
.text-highlight.off span {
   background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<audio id="adi" controls>
  <source src="https://ia802508.us.archive.org/5/items/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3"/>
</audio>

<button id="toggleTxt">Highlight on</button>

<div class="text-highlight">
  <pre>
    <span id="ts0.5">Ok, we're trying this for a second time</span> , <span id="ts3">to test the ability...</span>
    </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: When I click the button it makes the whole text highlighted with white background.  I need it to be with a normal colorless bg.

Comment: @Mike, I am not sure if I follow you here, care to demonstrate with screenshot?

Comment: @Mike, I moved all style changes to CSS. should be easier to handle.

Comment: Thanks for your patience..  It worked good, but not when I toggle back on, it removed the white highlighting from the read part.  I mean when clicking it back on, it should show the white background on the previously highlighted text as it was..

Comment: @Mike, no problem, the first impression was that you want no special styling for previous `span`s.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `removeEventListener`: `audi.removeEventListener(f1)`

Or you can have a function before your `f1()` function, `var enabled = true`, and in f1, return at the beginning if `enabled === false`, and write your button click listeners to change the `enabled` variable.